# How to clear keys when the WPF application is installed or updated?

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms, properties, key

I am working on the WPF application using xamarin.forms, Here I am saving the login user details in Application properties. Here I am getting a problem when I uninstall and reinstall the application the keys are not removing.

Is there any way to remove those Keys when the application is Updated or reinstalled?

I am saving the details as below:
 Application.Current.Properties["LoggedInDate"] = DateTime.Now;
Application.Current.Properties["CurrentUserName"] = userDetails.Name;

Comment: what keys are u talking about?

Comment: wpf and xamarin forms are frameworks all together. Maybe you want to say XAML ?

Comment: @AvinashReddy, I have updated my question on how I am saving the values to keys, can you please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such service to use (at the moment at least). Your keys should be stored **per-user** based on login credentials. When application loads you need to map those settings on the AppState. You won't have to find a bunch of workarounds when you have a well organized architecture. Stop doing hacks, do it right!

Way to go in my opinion.

1. Store the keys in a small database (SQLite), User -> hasMany Preferences. At login time load in memory the user with its preferences.
2. If you don't want to have a database you can store the preferences in local storage [good library](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage). Key should be something like userName_LoggedInDate.

Comment: Thanks for the replay @Dragos Stoica, can you please guide me in a right way. As my problem once I logged into the application and without doing log out, I have reinstalled. Now I am checking whether the keys are present then allowing the user to see a certain page if the keys are not presently taking him to log in. As the keys are nullifying after the reinstallation of the application if any other user gets logins to the application able to find my screens as I was login the application earlier.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will try those ways.